# Hugo Error add site dependencies: load resources: loading templates: parse failed: unexpected unterminated quoted string in command

Tags: netlify, hugo

I keep getting this error when running

```sh
hugo
```

from the terminal. I cant seem to figure out why it's shooting this error. I have labelled line 54 where the error is happening.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!-- footer -->
<footer class="bg-secondary position-relative">
  <img src="{{`images/backgrounds/map.png` | absURL }}" class="img-fluid overlay-image" alt="">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
          <h4 class="text-white mb-5">About</h4>
          <p class="text-light">{{ .Site.Params.footer.about.about | markdownify }} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
          <h4 class="text-white mb-5">Company</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {{ range .Site.Menus.footer }}
            <li><a href="{{ .URL | absURL }}" class="text-light d-block mb-3">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="bg-white p-4">
            <h3>Contact us</h3>
            <form action="{{ .Site.Params.form.formAction | safeURL }}">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Full name">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Email address">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
          <p class="text-light mb-0">{{ .Site.Params.copyright.copyright | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul class="list-inline text-md-right text-center">
            {{ range .Site.Params.social }}
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="d-block p-3 text-white" href="{{ .link | safeURL }}"><i
                  class="{{ .icon }}"></i></a></li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- /footer -->


<!--LINE 54 -->{{ "
<!-- Google Map API -->" | safeHTML }}
<script src="{{ .Site.Params.gmapAPI | absURL }}"></script>
{{ "
<!-- JS Plugins -->" | safeHTML }}
{{ range .Site.Params.plugins.js}}
<script src="{{ .URL | absURL }}"></script>
{{ end }}
{{ "
<!-- Main Script -->" | safeHTML }}
{{ $script := resources.Get "js/script.js" | minify}}
<script src="{{ $script.Permalink }}"></script>
{{ "
<!-- google analitycs -->" | safeHTML }}
<script>
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', '{{ .Site.Params.googleAnalitycsID }}', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
{{ "
<!-- Wiggly Script -->" | safeHTML }}
{{ $script := resources.Get "js/wiggly.js" | minify}}
<script src="{{ $script.Permalink }}"></script>
```

**Error: add site dependencies: load resources: loading templates: "/Volumes/DEV/ccdd/ccdd2022/themes/agen-hugo/layouts/partials/footer.html:54:1": parse failed: template: partials/footer.html:54: unexpected unterminated quoted string in command**

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this one out after some messing around after *REMOVING* the following from each item

```html
{{ "
<!-- Wiggly Script -->" | safeHTML }}
```

---

the footer now appears as such

```html
<!-- footer -->
<footer class="bg-secondary position-relative">
  <img src="{{`images/backgrounds/map.png` | absURL }}" class="img-fluid overlay-image" alt="">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
          <h4 class="text-white mb-5">About</h4>
          <p class="text-light">{{ .Site.Params.footer.about.about | markdownify }} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
          <h4 class="text-white mb-5">Company</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            {{ range .Site.Menus.footer }}
            <li><a href="{{ .URL | absURL }}" class="text-light d-block mb-3">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="bg-white p-4">
            <h3>Contact us</h3>
            <form action="{{ .Site.Params.form.formAction | safeURL }}">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Full name">
              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Email address">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control mb-4 px-0" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
          <p class="text-light mb-0">{{ .Site.Params.copyright.copyright | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul class="list-inline text-md-right text-center">
            {{ range .Site.Params.social }}
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="d-block p-3 text-white" href="{{ .link | safeURL }}"><i
                  class="{{ .icon }}"></i></a></li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- /footer -->




<script src="{{ .Site.Params.gmapAPI | absURL }}"></script>


{{ range .Site.Params.plugins.js}}
<script src="{{ .URL | absURL }}"></script>
{{ end }}



{{ $script := resources.Get "js/script.js" | minify}}
<script src="{{ $script.Permalink }}"></script>

{{ $script := resources.Get "js/wiggly.js" | minify}}
<script src="{{ $script.Permalink }}"></script>

<script>
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', '{{ .Site.Params.googleAnalitycsID }}', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Nice mate, just for the sake of googlers to this page, comments in Hugo are: {{/*
*/}} - not:  
{{ "<!-- Wiggly Script -->" | safeHTML }}  
If you want an HTML comment - just put it in.  <!-- Comment here -->